# Sharepoint calculated column to show today's date and NEVER update

Tags: calculated-column

I have a simple custom list. I want to be able to insert a check in a yes/no box and have the date that box was checked appear in another column. I am able to achieve this, but when that list item is modified, that date updates. I want it to never change unless that checkbox is cleared. Below is my current formula

```
=IF([YES/NO Column]=TRUE,TODAY(),"")
```

Again, that works, but updates with each change. How can I get it to be static?

I have also tried NOW() and [Modified] with the same results. I DO NOT have access to sharepoint designer to do any of this so it needs to be a formula or script of some sort i can use. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello @sscandrett , Your feedback is very important 1. Are the below answers didn't helped you? 2. do you need any further clarifications? if yes, please comment to the provided answers with your clarifications to can help you or edit your question with these clarifications, else please upvote and mark the correct answer that helped you as accepted to close this question. Also, please check [Tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) to know how can you accept the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**How can I get it to be static?**

Unfortunately,  `Today()` value will not preserve the first saved [Today] value! it will be recalculated again to get the current date at each Edit Item.

For more details check, [The Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated Column Formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

**Workarounds**

- **In case,** you need to be always static, try to use `[Created]` field.
- **In case,** you need to change it based on a specific condition, so try to create a `SharePoint designer workflow` as the following

  - Create a new field called `MyToday`
  - In your workflow set this `[MyToday]` field with the `[Created]` field.
  - Add IF condition if the Yes/No field equal Yes, then set  `[MyToday]` to `[Modified]`

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot use SharePoint Designer for a workflow solution, about your only option is to add JavaScript to the NewForm.aspx page for that list. While this is probably best done using SharePoint Designer, you could edit that page and add a Content Editor web part that includes the JavaScript. The checkbox column would be a Yes/No column. The JavaScript would have two parts. One would copy the current date into the Date or Single Line of Text column when the check box is checked. The second would set the date column edit control to read-only or read-write, depending on the status of the checkbox.

How are your JavaScript skills? Do you have access to a JavaScript developer?

If InfoPath is permitted in your SharePoint farm, it could be used to replace the default New/Edit forms to implement your needs. Most likely just using its built-in features, and if not with some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Modified date instead of Today in your code so that everytime they will update the item your calculated column can somehow be updated.